# Modem-manager-gui breaks after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, network-manager, modem-manager

I was using `modem-manager-gui` successfully before the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. I was on Ubuntu 21.10 previously.

The output

```
** (modem-manager-gui:19629): WARNING **: 23:55:47.324: Network Manager >= 0.9.0: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault at address: 0x20
Stack trace:
1. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f530038d540]
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f530038d540]
3. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_n_children+0x1d) [0x7f530040737d]
4. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modem-manager-gui/modules/libmodcm_nm09.so(+0x3bc0) [0x7f52fc03abc0]
5. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_connections_enum+0x6d) [0x55a12d105d4d]
6. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a520) [0x55a12d126520]
7. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_devices_open+0x1c0) [0x55a12d10af90]
8. modem-manager-gui(+0x415d2) [0x55a12d11d5d2]
9. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a7a2) [0x55a12d1267a2]
```

I removed the configuration files to make it ask again for the devices to use, tried to select something different to NetworkManager (I selected Undefined), but still breaks the same.

I don't know which file it is looking for and not finding. And the setting seems right. NetworkManager version is `1.36.4-2ubuntu1` so it fits with ">= 0.9.0". Or not?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It is an incompatibility with new versions of network-manager packages:

Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modem-manager-gui/+bug/1971435

Until the bug is fixed I have found two options:

**A)** If you need the SMS functionality without internet connection management functions:

1. Remove the SIM card and connect the modem.
2. Launch the modem-manager-gui. Now it will boot without errors.
3. Change connection manager to "pppd >= 2.4.5". Edit->Preferences->Modules and apply.
4. Reset modem-manager-gui, introduce SIM card again and connect the modem.

The SMS functionality will be work now.

**B)** Internet connection management functions will need a network-manager downgrade:

Source: https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/cant-start-modem-manager-gui-with-simcard-on/22749

Comment: Thanks on the feedback. I use it for internet, connecting and disconnecting is not the issue but the USSD commands which we must use to reload the credit on the SIM. Currently doing it with `mmcli`. Here is for checking available credit, for example `mmcli -m 0 --3gpp-ussd-initiate='*222#'`

I'll end up with an script and using it via `dmenu`. One GUI app less ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix (no need to remove/re-insert the SIM-card):

1. Remove the plugin library file which caused the crash. On Debian the file name is: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modem-manager-gui/modules/libmodcm_nm09.so`
2. Move the file to another directory, and start the `modem-manager-gui`. It will use the next available plugin automatically, which is `pppd` in my case. Check the `modem-manager-gui` preferences, `pppd` plugin should be selected.
3. Quit `modem-manager-gui`, it will save this preference setting.
4. Now you can move back the Network Manager plugin library file (`libmodcm_nm09.so`) to its original location and run `modem-manager-gui`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo rm -fr /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modem-manager-gui/modules/libmodcm_nm09.so` and unplugging and replugging the dlink 222 worked for me.