# LTE Modem EM7455 stop working after Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade

Tags: 22.04, modem

Perhaps related to [Modem-manager-gui breaks after update to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405439/modem-manager-gui-breaks-after-update-to-ubuntu-22-04) but I managed  in that case by not using `modem-manager-gui` but `mmcli`.

Now, after a certain upgrade (perhaps 15 days ago) the modem is not getting active at all.

Modem is recognized as:

```
mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Sierra Wireless, Incorporated] Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
```

The SIM card is active and have credit. Is not even possible to initiate USSD commands.

When using an old ISO (Lubuntu 21.10) it works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newest version of ModemManager the automatic FCC unlock is disabled. You can see here: https://modemmanager.org/docs/modemmanager/fcc-unlock/
To use the modem again you must FCC unlock the modem.

For the Lenovo-shipped EM7455:

sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/1199:9079

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing `libqmi-utils` as suggested by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1968581/comments/4

Not in the link, but I also restarted `ModemManager` service.

Now is just `modem-manager-gui` the one that is broken with the following output:

```
~ modem-manager-gui

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:51.363: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed
Connection manager: Network Manager >= 0.9.0
Modem manager: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.063: g_strrstr: assertion 'haystack != NULL' failed

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.103: g_variant_lookup_value: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary,
G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{s*}")) || g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary, G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{o*}"))' failed

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.103: g_variant_lookup_value: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary,
G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{s*}")) || g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary, G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{o*}"))' failed

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.103: g_variant_lookup_value: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary,
G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{s*}")) || g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary, G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{o*}"))' failed

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.103: g_variant_lookup_value: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary,
G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{s*}")) || g_variant_is_of_type (dictionary, G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{o*}"))' failed

(modem-manager-gui:6140): GLib-CRITICAL **: 00:07:52.103: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault at address: 0x20
Stack trace:
1. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f8d75cd7540]
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_bit_lock+0x50) [0x7f8d75cd7540]
3. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_variant_n_children+0x1d) [0x7f8d75d5137d]
4. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/modem-manager-gui/modules/libmodcm_nm09.so(+0x3bc0) [0x7f8d70077bc0]
5. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_connections_enum+0x6d) [0x55d2f3383d4d]
6. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a520) [0x55d2f33a4520]
7. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_devices_open+0x1c0) [0x55d2f3388f90]
8. modem-manager-gui(+0x414fe) [0x55d2f339b4fe]
9. modem-manager-gui(+0x4a7a2) [0x55d2f33a47a2]
```

but I can manage with `mmcli`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with Ubuntu 22 and Thinkpad Z13 in 2022:

```
gdbus.error.org.freedesktop.modermmanager1.error.core.wrongstate. cannot register modem: not yet enabled
```

The modem was disabled by default and no way to turn it on.

After hours of googling and trying various solutions with `ls` and **modem enable/disable scripts, the `libmbim-utils` solved it**:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install libmbim-utils
$ sudo mbimcli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --quectel-query-radio-state
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Radio state retrieved: 'fcc-locked'
```

```bash
$ sudo mbimcli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --quectel-set-radio-state=on
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Successfully requested to enable radio
```

```bash
$ sudo mbimcli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --quectel-query-radio-state
[/dev/cdc-wdm0] Radio state retrieved: 'on'
```

Now the modem is enabled!

Credit goes to non-https website: https://koo.fi/blog/2022/12/21/enabling-quectel-em05-g-modem-on-linux/

Comment: for some reason I keep receiving "NotDeviceSupport"

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).